# How to go from 2nd viewcontroller to the first viewcontroller with a back button?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, xcode5, back-button

I have 2 viewcontrollers in my storyboard. This is for my game. The first view controller is the menu (with play button) when you click the play button it modals (by modal i mean when you hold down the control key and click the button and drag it to the view) to the 2nd viewcontroller (Which is my game scene). That works perfectly. My problem is I have put a button in my 2nd viewcontroller which is a back button. I modaled it to the menu (first viewcontroller). That works perfectly to , but when you click play again for the second time after having pressed the back button once from the game, once you are playing the game everything starts glitching. I really need your help?

Comment: `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];`

Comment: If you are using a nav controller then `[navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];`

Comment: Im kind of new to xcode. Sorry. I held the control button and clicked on my button and dragged it to the 1st viewcontroller. (this is for the back button on my 2nd viewcontroller) my problem is once you click the back button it goes to the first view controller but then once you click play again and it goes back to the 2nd viewcontroller the game starts glitching.

Comment: I am not using nav controller

Comment: Take a look at the answer and do your research first.  This information is readily accessible and they are the beginning basics.  SO is not the place to get answers to those kinds of questions.

Comment: What you're doing is wrong because you are basically creating the first view controller again in memory and you never actually dismiss the second view controller which uses up resources.

Comment: I did my research but couldnt find anything useful. You see, when i click my back button it works and goes back to the first view controller, but once you click play again and once it goes back the the game once you start playing everythings starts gliching and not working corectly

Comment: evan so what is your solution what can i do? Please if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you are doing.

Try using a UINavigationController instead of hard linking buttons to views, that way you get a stack with your views where you can push and pop whatever you want.

Have a look at [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

Comment: Sorry but this didnt really help.

Comment: No problem, if you don't want to use a navController you can use [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; which should work, but its best practice to stick to UINavigationController, keep that link for future reference.

Comment: @user3466875 it's incredibly helpful... it answers your question.  Learn the basics first before asking these questions here please.

Comment: sorry evan im a 13 year old and iv started making a game and now im stuck

Comment: Mate, its great that you are starting at a young age, hopefully you will get better, but you will run into much more problems down the road if you do things the wrong way, its not wrong to ask, but you should try and do things right, from the very start.

Comment: Thanks MrHaze Im so sorry if iv cause u trouble or annoyed you but i searched all over the web and all i found useful was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22119913/xcode-issues-when-coming-from-another-view-controller

Comment: I am using seagues to link my back button to first viewcontroler

Comment: That will work well if you are using one viewController, but for multiple views (assuming you aren't building another (flappy bird :P)) using a navigation controller is the best way, you have more autonomy over which views get displayed and which get popped.

Comment: LOL as a matter of fact im am building another flappy bird

Comment: So can you give me some advice on what to do now

Comment: So i have the main menu and the game

Comment: now i want to add a back button in the game to go back to the main menu

Comment: without making it glitch by using seagues

Comment: Well, it depends how you want to do it. I've never written a game on IOS but I would imagine you don't even need view controllers (I.e just move a view, or scroll it in). When you click a button you want to trigger animations, and from there you want to set a game status, to know where you are at this point of time, are you on menu? Start screen? Etc... that's how you go about doing it (I think, I could be wrong). But yes, for menu you probably want a view controller to pop in, just have a look at the like I shared, use navigation controllers where you can, it doesn't need to have the top bar.